# iOS UI Not showing where it should be

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, interface, uibutton

Good day, I am sitting with an issue regarding my UI...

I am busy developing an app for iPhones, but the UI does not work together well...

I set a custom tableviewcell, and have a button that should be at the end of the cell, but the display is not correct, however if i take the frame it seems to be correct. Here is a screenshot of what happens when I scroll down...
[image]

In my code I set the arrow button with the following line of code:

```
cell.button.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableview.frame.size.width-60, (height-40)/2, 40, 40);
```

The idea is that I have a 20px space behind the button...

Note I am not using AutoLayout etc...

And if i run the code for the button and I log all the positions of the button, the positions are all 100% the same...

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Use constraints

Comment: @Sulthan Constraints require the use of AutoLayout, which I do not have enabled,since it would take more time to get AutoLayout to work on a project which never had it on... Most of out projects come from a pre-AutoLayout time, and it has a fairly large UI

Comment: @Burnie777 can you check my answer?

Comment: @ReinierMelian going to now...

Comment: Where is the button, what is the parent view? And why you don't use cell.frame insted table.view.frame?

Comment: @m1sh0 My button is part of a custom declared cell... The width of the cell is the width of the tableview as well...

Comment: @Burnie777 any feedback about this?

Comment: @ReinierMelian thank you this works 100%

Comment: Your welcome @Burnie777 glad to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your code for adjusting your button frame in the layoutSubViews method of your cell class

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width-60, (self.bounds.size.height-40)/2, 40, 40);
}
```